# Get for each parent record all child records of a specific object type in a map<parentid, list<childobject>>

Tags: apex, query, map

I'm trying to figure out the correct approach to get for each parent record in a list : all the specific sobject child records related to that specific parent record.
And I would like to arrange them in `map<parentid, list<specific child object>>()`

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SFSE! Please explore Salesforce Maps, you should be able to find the answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Map, Yes you can provide Id as ParentId and in values as List of Child records. Eg.

```
Map<Id,List<Contact>> myMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    for(Account a:[SELECT id,(SELECT Id FROM Contacts)FROM Account]){
        myMap.put(a.Id,a.Contacts);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  any idea on how I can iterate on that map values inside a for loop : for each account and for each contact of that account

Comment: @Fatih I would recommend asking a new question for that... look at the [`Map.values()` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_values)